# How do I check the Content-type header before getting the body using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http

I need a way/library that is able to fetch a web page like in the example below:

```
result = http_client.get('/some_page.html') do |response|
  if response.content_type == 'text/html' and response.code == 200
    response.read_body #the headers are returned along with page body
  else
    #not reading the body so only the headers are returned without body
  end
end
```

Now in case of a "text/html" page with a success response:

```
p result.code #>200
p result.content_type #>text/html
p result.body #><DOCTYPE html...
```

In case of a non-"text/html" page or non 200 page:

```
p result.code #>404
p result.content_type #>text/html
p result.body #>nil
```

It all must be done in one request to the web server. It's not acceptable to make a HTTP HEAD request to check the headers and then a HTTP GET request to get the body because it would result in 2 requests.

What gem/library offer such possibilities?

**Update**

I found a solution digging into the net/http library:

```
client.request_get(uri.request_uri) do |res|
  if res.content_type == 'text/html'
    res.read_body
  else
    res.instance_eval {@body_exist = false}
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually the code in my post Update is exacly what I wanted. I start the request and looking at the content-type for example. If I see that the page has the content-type text/html which I need - I download the body, but if it's not text/html (e.g. a 2Gb movie) - I do not, and what I get is just the headers for information. This way I can save a lot of time and a lot more bandwidth and do not bother servers with double amount of requests. Did you ever see Google to make a HEAD request before a GET one when crawling the web? But I doubt Google downloads everything mentioned in the urls.

Comment: First: I know what a `head` request is, how to use it and I know its purpose. Second: The `If-*` headers are used for caching mechanism, which is not what the question was about. I would use the `Accept` header if the servers would respond as expected with a 406 status code (see [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) 14.1), but the majority of them does not.

Comment: Even Google and Yahoo are happy to answer with a 200 text/html status when I include the `Accept: nonexisting/contenttype` header. Who is a bad citizen now? Third: You keep answering to the WRONG QUESTION. The question was not 'what a `head` request is' or 'how do I use the `head` request' or 'how is better to check the headers before downloading the content'. The question was 'how do I check the headers and download the content IF I need it, all in one request'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution digging into the net/http library:

```
client.request_get(uri.request_uri) do |res|
  if res.content_type == 'text/html'
    res.read_body
  else
    res.instance_eval {@body_exist = false}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an HTTP HEAD returns what you want.

HEAD should be supported, as this link suggests

http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient

Comment: I need to get headers and body (just in specific cases) in one request. It will result in 2 request if I make a HTTP HEAD request first to check headers and then a HTTP GET request to get the body.

Comment: yes, I'm afraid that is correct and is a consequence of the nature of http, unless you do streaming (chunked transfer)